# Изменить параметр в зависимости от условия

Tags: java, android

Как в классе своём можно сделать так, чтоб данный параметр менялся на false?

```
app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
```

Пробую в коде писать следующее

```
passwordEye.setPasswordVisibilityToggleEnabled(false);
```

Но он помимо того чтобы убирать серый глазик, убирает и восклицателньый цнак.
Как можно сделатьтак чтобы знак оставался?

Comment: Можешь в res/values создать xml в котором будет храниться твоя переменная. в твоей строке app:passwordToggleEnabled="true" тру меняешь на имя переменной, а её значение задаешь уже в коде. Почитать можно тут https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html

Comment: @SviatVolkov не совсем понятно как это будет в классе, именно эта замена.